# Flash is ignoring my most of my tags in a HTML TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, htmltext

I've been trying to figure out for a while now. I usually manage to make my textFields work properly, but this is just driving me nuts.

I have this TextField that I inject HTML formatted text (contained in a XML file). For some reason, almost all my tags are ignored (`<b>`,`<i>`,`<u>`,`<ul>` and `<li>`). I can only get it to render `<br />` tags properly. I could use a StyleSheet, but I don't think it would make my lists work...

Here's how things are set up:

Text I inject:

```
<text>
    <![CDATA[<b>Some bold text </b>and some normal text <br/><u>This text is underlined</u> normal text to compare<br/><i/>This text is italic</i>]]>
</text>
```

How my TextField is set:

```
// When my Class' setup method is called, I set those properties
_tf = _transcript.getTextFormat();
_tf.font = "Verdana";
_tf.size = 12;
_transcript.embedFonts  = true;
_transcript.multiline   = true;
_transcript.autoSize    = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
_transcript.wordWrap    = true;

// In an function, later on
_transcript.htmlText = transcript;  // transcript is a parameter. Basically, the XML I wrote above
_transcript.setTextFormat(_tf);
```

I **DO** have Verdana embed (as well as the variants). I made sure by generating a size report  **and** tracing Font.enumerateFonts(). If I output the textField's htmlText after having set it up, I get this:

`<P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12" COLOR="#FFFFFF" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Some bold text and some normal text </FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12" COLOR="#FFFFFF" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">This text is underlined normal text to compare</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12" COLOR="#FFFFFF" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">This text is italic</FONT></P>`

I'm really out of ideas on why nothing's working, if anyone had any idea, I'd really appreciate it!!

Thank you

**Edit:** So I decided to test having no CDATA in my XML, and adding the `<b>` tag in my AS3 code. Didn't work either. I don't get how I can have my fonts correctly embed, but Flash refusing to use them.

Comment: Not sure but perhaps it could be that the HTML is wrapped in CDATA that has some side effect. I would test stripping that out, before assigning the text to .htmlText.

Comment: are you sure `htmlText` accepts `XML`?

Comment: I need the CDATA, or my XML file would interpret the HTML tags as being XML tags. (Just to be sure, after writing this I tested it. I do need the CDATA or my XML starts acting up)

Comment: Yes, you need CDATA in the XML, but you could try stripping it out just before you assign the text to .htmlText, in ActionScript (not when you generate the XML).

Comment: Yep, like I said, before sending my reply I tested it out, didn't work. Also look at my edit in the original post. I tried having no tags at all in the XML and it didn't work either.

Comment: @gCardinal could you please include the exact code snippet, I'm not bothered about the text content, its the tags you're using I'm interested in. Currently I have to adjust you text code to make it compile with a text field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok to get this to work, I have used the following syntax:

```
<mx:Text>
    <mx:htmlText>
        <![CDATA[<b>Some bold text </b>and some normal text <br/><u>This text is underlined</u> normal text to compare<br/><i/>This text is italic</i>]]>
    </mx:htmlText>
</mx:Text>
```

I didnt try including any of the extra script you have in your question, but it seems to handle the html tags ok like this.

Also here is the livedocs reference I used to check my syntax...

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html

Looking back at your question I've just realised that you probably aren't using Flex, ok so this is Flex specific, sorry.